# Format Graph ggcuminc - Cumulative Incidence

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm on a project to evaluate the competitive risk between my variable of interest and the competitive event. I created the following code that returned a graph.

```
cuminc(Surv(TIME,STATUS,type="mstate") ~ SEX, BASE) %>%
ggcuminc(outcome = c(“1”,“2”)) + xlim(0,90) + ylim(0,0.2) + add_risktable() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 90, by = 10), limits = c(0, 90)) +theme_classic() + theme(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction = “horizontal”)
```

[image]

I'd like to insert some information and formatting, but I'm not having success.

1 - Insert the p-value (0.12 and 0.25) and the name of the variables (death and non-death) at the end of the upper and lower lines;

2 - Change the legend, because 1 and 2 are coming. I would like to change it to death and non-death. I tried using “rename” inside “outcome” and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer your question if you provided a small dataset to reproduce. I have made an attempt to give an example answer below, but you may need to edit to fit your data and plot.

1. one straight forward way to add p-values and the name of the variable would be to use `annotate()`
2. to change the label in the legend from 1 and 2 to 'non-death' and 'death' you can set the labels in the factor of your outcome.

```
   # I'm assuming you have 3 levels for STATUS: 0/1/2 ; 

   BASE$STATUS <- factor(BASE$STATUS, 
                         levels = c(0,1,2), 
                         labels = c("censor", "death", "non-death")
```

A demonstration:

```
      library(tidycmprsk)
      library(ggsurvfit)
      
      # Using 'trial' dataset from the tidycmprsk package
      # outcome variable is already a labelled factor, so reset to numeric

      trial$death_cr <- as.numeric(trial$death_cr)

      # factor with levels and labels whatever you want them to be
      trial$death_cr <- factor(trial$death_cr,
                               levels = c(0,1,2),
                               labels = c("censor", "cancer death", "non-cancer death"))

      # plot
      cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, data = trial) %>%
        ggcuminc(outcome = c("C death", "non-C death")) +
        ylim(0,0.5) +
        add_risktable() +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 25, by = 5),
                        limits = c(0, 30)) +
        theme_classic() +
        theme(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction = "horizontal") +
        annotate("text", x = 28, y = 0.29, label = "non-C death p = 0.12") +
        annotate("text", x = 27, y = 0.24, label = "death p = 0.25")
```

[image]